# QEventLoop discard some signal

Tags: qt, qeventloop

I have a question about QEventLoop: how to set a QEventLoop  to discard some signal

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Dialog *_dlg;
public:
    MyThread(Dialog* dlg)
        : _dlg(dlg)
    {

    }
    virtual void run()
    {
        QTimer* _timer;
        _timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),
                _dlg, SLOT(timeout()), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
        _timer->start(3000);

        QEventLoop loop;
        loop.exec(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
    } 
};

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this, SLOT(click()));

    MyThread* thread = new MyThread(this);
    thread->start();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::click()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox(this);
    msgBox.setText("click.");
    msgBox.exec();
}

void Dialog::timeout()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox(this);
    msgBox.setText("timeout.");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

this is my code  when start this programe , every 5 second a timeout QMessageBox will be show  .
but i want if i press button then  show the click messagebox and  do not show the  timeout messagebox..
i failed to find any method to do it

[image]

Comment: i just want that msgBox.exec in Dialog::click do not handle timeout signal

Comment: But, there's no connection created in your `QEventLoop` using the `connect`. And, all the timer events are handled by the main thread of `QApplication`. `QEventLoop` doesn't block other events.

Comment: Is your thread only for your timer? You don't need a thread for that. Anyway, you can just stop the timer when you press the button that shows the "click" message box. Then start the timer again when that message box has been closed. Or if you don't want to stop the timer, you can use [`QObject::blockSignals`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals).

Comment: Why do you need an instance of a `QEventLoop`? Just run `exec()` instead.

Comment: this is just an example. My actual work is complicated.  main thread show dialog , another thread do something and will emit some signals to the main thread. when i show a messagebox in main thread, at the same time, a signal arrived . this will lead to some consistency problems.